# Pass multiple commandline arguments to ECS Fargate from Step Function

Tags: python, amazon-ecs, aws-step-functions

We have an ECS Fargate task in Python that is currently parsing commandline arguments to determine which sub-task to do (update a dataset, remove a dataset, etc.).

We are invoking this via a step function and I'm curious what the best way to structure the ContainerOverrides is.

We have something working with

```
"ContainerOverrides": [
  {
     "Command.$": "$.subtask_command"
```

where `$.subtask_command` is something like `[ "sub_task", "--input1", "input1_value"...]`

But it seems like it would be much cleaner to have just the input variables be passed to the step function and then the step function could have something like:

```
"ContainerOverrides": [
  {
     "Command.$": [ "sub_task", "--input1", "<somehow get this from step function input>"...]
```

What I'm curious is:

1. Is this even possible?  I've been struggling with it for a while and can't find a sample
2. Is this the best way to use ECS/Fargate or is there a way to directly call a python function with an input object?

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible using the `States.Array` intrinsic function:

```json
"ContainerOverrides": [
  {
     "Command.$": "States.Array('sub_task', '--input1', $.some.input.value, '--input2', 'wazzup')"
  }
]
```